# How do I read and use the Unity Doc Scripting API as I develop my own games?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So this is not a specific coding problem, but a more general question about getting the most out of the Unity Scripting API. I have been doing Unity tutorials on and off for the past 2 - 3 years and now I want to turn it into a serious career in VR/XR. Right now I am doing some FPS and RPG tutorials to get the fundamentals down for my first game, however I want to become less reliant on Youtube vids and more on the Unity Scripting manual API.

Main problem is enhancing GameObjects with the correct namespaces and their definitions. How can I match the the correct namespaces to Game Objects like Characters to Game Managers to Terrain to RigidBodys and Colliders and further fine tune basic tasks Animation, Item Collection, and FPS-game features?

I'm sorry this is so broad but I'm trying to become more fluent on the fly with C# in Unity. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is probably way to broad for this community ... but honestly, I dont even understand what your are talking about. Are you asking how to read an API in general??

Comment: Yes ! Like I understand Namespaces like Unity.Engine at the top of a component lets a script perform a variety of methods and actions on its GameObject, but how do I match the right namespaces to a PlayerController script or a NavMesh component/script.

Comment: Well you google for e.g. [`Unity PlayerController API`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Unity+PlayerController+API) which brings you to the ([deprecaded](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001252086-UNet-Deprecation-FAQ)) [PlayerController API](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.PlayerController.html) .. there you can see it belongs to the `UnityEngine.Networking` namespace

Comment: I don’t think your problem is that you can’t use the docs, I think your problem is that you can follow tutorials, but you can’t really code. I would suggest stopping with the tutorials and starting a programming course, either online, in person/at an institution, or with a book. Some of the things you have trouble with right now will become trivial once you actually become a programmer.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez totally, I am not fluent in C# for Unity, and I'm just understanding how differnent variables work in components with functions. That's why I Want to focus more on using manual, I also think it is a matter of trial and error.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I love StackO already!